# Return Number of published posts in a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php
    $counter=1;
    $counter_new=0;
    $args = array('posts_per_page' =>-1,'orderby' => 'post_date','order' =>'DESC','post_type' => 'interview','post_status' => 'publish',            
    'suppress_filters' => true );query_posts( $args );while (have_posts($args)) : the_post();
    if($counter < 8)
    {
        $counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        $counter_new++;
        $counter=1;
    }
endwhile;
?>
```

I saw someone else code to find the number of post, as record increase it is not efficient. What is the right way to do? It looks stupid now.

Answer (score 3):

In case you use WPML wp_count_post() will not show correct count of posts for given language. Use this instead:

```
$posts = get_posts('post_type=yourcustomposttype&suppress_filters=0&posts_per_page=-1');
$count = count($posts); 
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [wp_count_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) function.

For your example:

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts('interview');
$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
```

$published_posts will return the number of published posts in your 'interview' custom post type.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

One of the other answers won't work if you have WMPL and translations. The other one will work, but will be very inefficient.

With WPML, try this instead:

```php
function my_count_posts( string $post_type = 'post', string $language_code = '', string $post_status = 'publish' ): int {
    global $wpdb;


    $default_language_code = apply_filters( 'wpml_default_language', null );
    $language_code         = $language_code !== '' ? $language_code : $default_language_code;
    $translation_param     = $default_language_code == $language_code ? "IS NULL" : "= '{$default_language_code}'";

    $query = <<<SQL
                SELECT COUNT( {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID )
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
                    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}icl_translations ON {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb->prefix}icl_translations.element_id
                WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}icl_translations.language_code = '{$language_code}'
                  AND {$wpdb->prefix}icl_translations.source_language_code $translation_param
                  AND {$wpdb->prefix}icl_translations.element_type = 'post_{$post_type}'
                  AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_status = '$post_status'
                SQL;

    return $wpdb->get_var( $query );
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
// counts published "posts" in the default language
$count = my_count_posts();

// counts posts of `post_type=custom_post_type` in the current language
$count = my_count_posts('custom_post_type', apply_filters( 'wpml_current_language', '' ));
```